# Margin auto not aligning Item in horixontal center

Tags: css, margin

```
.logo {
    border: 1px solid goldenrod;
}

.logo img {
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

the above is the CSS and its HTML is:the above is the CSS and its HTML is:the above is the CSS and its HTML is:the above is the CSS and its HTML is:the above is the CSS and its HTML is:the above is the CSS and its HTML is:the above is the CSS and its HTML is:the above is the CSS and its HTML is:the above is the CSS and its HTML is:the above is the CSS and its HTML is:

```
<header class="theader">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="https://demo.templatic.com/cartsy/wp-content/themes/Cartsy/images/logo.png" alt="" width="100px" height="auto">
            </div>          
        </header>
```

Comment: Images are inline elements and so do not respond to `margin`. Place `text-align:center` on `.logo.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

make it block and it will work

```
.logo img {
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why was I downvoted. I didn't posted spam?

Comment: it's fine fitnessninja
just your question was already has answered in the top link, because of that someone down voted you.
 you should check  and see if your question is not in the platform, if not than post your question, otherwise you will end up with down vote
have a good day my friend 
--mostafa--